# Вывод только 1 значение для переменных. Подскажите как исправить

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float C, F;
    {
        for (F = 0; F < 301; F += 20 );
        C = (5.0f / 9.0f) * (F - 32);
    
        printf("F = %5.3f\tC = %5.3f\n", F, C);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Задача выглядит так: составить
с применением цикла
for
таблицу перевода температур по
Фаренгейту
к
стоградусной
шкалы
Цельсия
для диапазона температур
0-300 ° F
с шагом изменения 20 ° F
, Если известна формула перевода:
C = (5/9) * (F-32)

Comment: Вносите уточнения прямо в тело вопроса - кнопка "править"

Comment: Что это за конструкция такая интересная { for(); }? Почему в учебниках for() {}, а у вас вот так своеобразно?

Comment: @EzikBro тело цикла может опускаться, если в нем нет необходимости. Тогда ```;``` ставится сразу после блока условия, а фигурные скобки опускаются. Хотя тут скорее всего не этот случай)

Comment: @SelfishCrawler конечно. Однако вы правда считаете, что автор вопроса нуждается именно в таком варианте использования цикла? Тем более я не думаю, что он действительно решил определить блок видимости для того, чтобы исполнять такой код.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего опечатки, будьте внимательнее: не там фигурная скобка, не нужна точка с запятой после блока цикла

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float C, F;
    for (F = 0; F < 301; F += 20 )
    {
        C = (5.0f / 9.0f) * (F - 32);
    
        printf("F = %5.3f\tC = %5.3f\n", F, C);
    }
    return 0;
}
```